# how to search and retrieve specific columns from a huge data

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(X..taminn = c(86L, 102L, 34L, 35L, 53L, 54L, 43L, 
31L, 62L, 54L), X..turtia = c(413L, 322L, 525L, 535L, 247L, 207L, 
241L, 440L, 189L, 221L), X..bestt = c(82L, 102L, 6L, 2L, 46L, 
1L, 39L, 7L, 62L, 54L), Best..F1..129..test = c(3079.3, 1512.9, 
497, 2804.5, 1353.7, 1597.6, 2005.1, 186.4, 1847.5, 1558.2), 
    best..F1..130..test = c(8972.7, 1944, 2022.7, 13001.7, 2085, 
    3228.6, 4948.5, 943.6, 1329, 2655.9), best..F1..131..test = c(2634.4, 
    1181.3, 505.2, 2802.4, 1573.2, 1707.6, 1585.9, 192.1, 809.2, 
    1219), how1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "High", "Not Found"), class = "factor"), 
    how2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("", "High", "Not Found"), class = "factor"), 
    how3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("", "High"), class = "factor"), Best.test...F1..129..test = c(3079.3, 
    1512.9, 497, 2804.5, 1353.7, 1597.6, 2005.1, 186.4, 1847.5, 
    1558.2), best.test...F1..130..test = c(8972.7, 1944, 2022.7, 
    13001.7, 2085, 3228.6, 4948.5, 943.6, 1329, 2655.9), best.test...F1..131..test = c(2634.4, 
    1181.3, 505.2, 2802.4, 1573.2, 1707.6, 1585.9, 192.1, 809.2, 
    1219), Best..test..129..test = c(3079.3, 1512.9, 497, 2804.5, 
    1353.7, 1597.6, 2005.1, 186.4, 1847.5, 1558.2), best..test..130..test = c(8972.7, 
    1944, 2022.7, 13001.7, 2085, 3228.6, 4948.5, 943.6, 1329, 
    2655.9), best..test..131..test = c(2634.4, 1181.3, 505.2, 
    2802.4, 1573.2, 1707.6, 1585.9, 192.1, 809.2, 1219)), .Names = c("X..taminn", 
"X..turtia", "X..bestt", "Best..F1..129..test", "best..F1..130..test", 
"best..F1..131..test", "how1", "how2", "how3", "Best.test...F1..129..test", 
"best.test...F1..130..test", "best.test...F1..131..test", "Best..test..129..test", 
"best..test..130..test", "best..test..131..test"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Basically, I want to extract all those columns that their name starts with

```
best..F1   
best..F2
.
.
```

is there a way to do it without going to the data one by one and find its place ?

Comment: We can try `df[startsWith(names(df), "best..F")]`

Comment: @akrun I get this error `could not find function "startsWith"`  and sessionInfo is R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: I use R 3.4.0 and it may be introduced recently as a base R function

Comment: @akrun you are right , I liked your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `startsWith` from `base R`

```
df[startsWith(names(df), "best..F")]
```

Comment: if I want to add another column which start with another name, is there any way inside your command? for example should I say "...." & "..."

Comment: I liked your answer

Comment: @nik According to the documentation `?startsWith`, the way to use is `cbind(
      startsWith(x1, "b"),
      startsWith(x1, "bl"),
      startsWith(x1, "bla"),
        endsWith(x1, "n"),
        endsWith(x1, "an"))`

Comment: @nik For example If you want to subset, 'best...' and 'how' then `df[startsWith(names(df), "how")|startsWith(names(df), "best..F")]`

Comment: It does not work, for exmaple if you want to get how column and then best..F , I did this `dfnew2 <- df[startsWith(names(df), c("how", "best..F"))]` look at the results

Comment: @nik I changed the comment

Comment: thanks, again it does not bring all the `best..F` ,  for example `df[startsWith(names(df), "how1")|startsWith(names(df), "best..F")]` which suppose to take the only how1 and best..F whatever best..F right?

Comment: @nik I get 5 columns with that command i..e 2 best and 3 how i.e. ` `df[startsWith(names(df), "how")|startsWith(names(df), "best..F")]#
   best..F1..130..test best..F1..131..test      how1      how2 how3`

Comment: this is true if you use `how` but if you use `how1` then it will not be

Comment: @nik In that case, the other values are different i.e. how2 and how3, but it returns `how1` `names(df[startsWith(names(df), "how1")|startsWith(names(df), "best..F")])
#[1] "best..F1..130..test" "best..F1..131..test" "how1"`

Answer (score 3):

You may try `grep` with like this:

```
df[,grep("^best\\.\\.F",names(df))]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(starts_with("best..F"))
```